# Get ColorThief to change box-shadow Color

Tags: javascript, css

How would I complete this script to have it edit the box-shadow color of #player1?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).ready(function(){
    var sourceImage = document.getElementById("art");
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
    var color = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
    document.getElementById("player1").style.['box-shadow'] = "rgb(" + color + ")";
   });
</script>
```

Also in the css, what should I put after

```
#player1 {box-shadow:() 5px;}
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery at all?

Comment: yes, I'm using jquery to run ColorThief

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

It is not necessary to have a default value for the `box-shadow` property of `#player1`, since it will be set by JavaScript when the page is loaded (This is what you intended to do right?). You may try the following:

#### Pure JavaScript

[DEMO (RGB value is hard-coded)](http://jsfiddle.net/tgsLf/)

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    var sourceImage = document.getElementById("art");
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
    var color = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
    document.getElementById('player1').style['boxShadow'] = '10px 10px 5px rgba('+ color[0] + ', ' + color[1] + ', ' + color[2] + ', 0.5)';
});
```

However, IE doesn't seem to support `.style['boxShadow']`. Alternatively, I recommend using jQuery, and you may try the following:

#### jQuery

[DEMO (RGB value is hard-coded)](http://jsfiddle.net/tgsLf/1/)

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    var sourceImage = document.getElementById("art");
    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
    var color = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
    $('#player1').css('box-shadow', '10px 10px 5px rgba('+ color[0] + ', ' + color[1] + ', ' + color[2] + ', 0.5)');
});
```

And this code snippet works in IE as well.

Comment: CSS is not initialized by JavaScript - it is initialized by the browser's native CSS engine (unless the engine itself was written in JavaScript, but that's not really the point), and then exposed to JavaScript via CSSOM APIs.

Comment: Sorry for my bad wording, by "initialized" I meant the CSS property is set when the page is loaded

Comment: I'm using jQuery, but in the example above, the box shadow color is already set to red I think (correct me if I'm wrong). Also when I try to run this script, ColorThief doesn't return any value and nothing is created for the box-shadow of #player1

Comment: You are right, I have hard-coded the box-shadow color to red in the demos to give you some idea on creating the box-shadow. I looked into the API of [Color Thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/), the `.getColor()` method returns a size 3 array that contains the RGB color of the image, so basically you can substitute the corresponding values in our `.css` method with these values. I have updated the code for your reference.